# NullPointer when mock an inject attribute using PowerMock

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I'm testing a class using PowerMock, and I'm getting null pointer exception when a field that would be mocked is null. I'm mocking two fields, one to Golf and another to Tango. Golf is mocked fine, but NullPointer happens to Golf.

PS: in order to decrease the complexity, I'm  boil down the code and it may looks don't need PowerMock, but in real case it is need.

Follow my code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Foo {


    @Inject
    private Tango tango;


    public int travel(Golf golf){

       Bar bar = new Bar();
       bar.setGolf(golf);
    
       return tango.fly(bar); // here tango is null, bar and golf are mocked
   }
}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class, Tango.class})
public class FooTest{

    @Mock
    Golf golfMock;

    @Mock
    Tango tangoBar;
    
    @Test
    public void travelTest(){

       List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("a","b");
       Bar barMock = new Bar();
       barMock.setList(testList);
    
       PowerMockito.whenNew(Bar.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(barMock);
       Foo fooMock = new Foo();
       Assert.assertTrue(fooMock.travel(golfMock) > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `new Foo()`, which creates a normal POJO. There's no mocking involved, and no injection.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon what the other reply has mentioned, here is a more explicit and therefore usually less error prone way to do mocking:

```
Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class); //initing a mock
when(foo.hello()).thenReturn("hello"); //mocking behavior
Bar bar = new Bar(foo); //dependency injecting the mock into a real class
```